# LNK2001 error when compiling on command line, but not in IDE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linker, cl.exe

I have a large VC++ project developed in Visual Studio 2010 that I need to be able to build from the command line using CL.exe.  In the IDE, the project builds successfully, but I haven't been able to build it on the command line.

I've mostly dealt with linker errors and have gotten it down to one:

```
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _WinMainCRTStartup
C:\<path_to>\Debug\LargeProject.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I found in the debug folder a file called "LargeProject.log" that shows the precise command line arguments that get called from the IDE when the IDE builds.  I've listed them here, if it helps.

(See edit notes at bottom of this question for some updates)

```
CL.exe /c /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D _MBCS /D _AFXDLL /Gm- /EHa /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Yc"StdAfx.h" /Fp"Debug\LargeProject.pch" /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:prompt "Source Files\stdafx.cpp" /wd4482 > testDump.txt
CL.exe /c /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D _MBCS /D _AFXDLL /Gm- /EHa /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Yu"StdAfx.h" /Fp"Debug\LargeProject.pch" /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:prompt <list of all source files except the following> /wd4482 > testDump.txt
CL.exe /c /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _DEBUG /D _MBCS /D _AFXDLL /Gm- /EHa /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Yu"StdAfx.h" /Fp"Debug\LargeProject.pch" /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc100.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:prompt "Source Files\LargeProject.cpp" /wd4482 > testDump.txt
rc.exe /D _DEBUG /D _AFXDLL /l"0x0409" /I"Debug\\" /nologo /fo"Debug\LargeProject.res" LargeProject.rc > testDump.txt
rc.exe /nologo /fo"Debug\LargeProject.exe.embed.manifest.res" "Debug\LargeProject_manifest.rc" > testDump.txt
link.exe /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /OUT:"C:\<path_to>\Debug\LargeProject.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO <list of libraries used> /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"Debug\LargeProject.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\<path_to>\Debug\LargeProject.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:\<path_to>\Debug\LargeProject.lib" /MACHINE:X86 "Debug\LargeProject.res" > testDump.txt
// note that I don't run any of the commands below because the above command
//   threw an error.
mt.exe /nologo /verbose /out:"Debug\LargeProject.exe.embed.manifest" /manifest "Debug\LargeProject.exe.intermediate.manifest" "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Include\Manifest\dpiaware.manifest" > testDump.txt
rc.exe /nologo /fo"Debug\LargeProject.exe.embed.manifest.res" "Debug\LargeProject_manifest.rc" > testDump.txt
link.exe /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /OUT:"C:\<path_to>\Debug\LargeProject.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO <list of libraries used> /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"Debug\LargeProject.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\<path to>\Debug\LargeProject.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:\<path_to>\Debug\LargeProject.lib" /MACHINE:X86 "Debug\LargeProject.res" > testDump.txt
```

As you can see, I ran each of these in sequence (until I got an error) and dumped the contents to testDump.txt.  Here's testDump.txt's contents after the first link.exe command

```
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _WinMainCRTStartup
C:\<path_to>\Debug\LargeProject.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I'm confused that I'm getting this error on the command line, but not from the IDE, which is presumably just running these commands behind the scenes.  It's also worth noting that I've run the vcvars32.bat file from my command prompt window, so it can't be a local environment variable issue.

**Edit:**
I've tried adding `msvcrt.lib` to the list of libraries in the link command.  This produced a new linker error:

```
msvcrt.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
C:\<path_to>\Debug\LargeProject.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I've read that this means the proper entry point wasn't defined in the project.  ie, that there should be a WinMain() function in the project to serve as the the entry point for the application.  That seems logical, but I haven't found that function and, to reiterate, the project compiles and links fine in the IDE, and presumably the log file I got these commands from is merely listing what the IDE was doing anyway.

There seem to be other CRT libraries.  I tried `msvcprt.lib`, but that yeilded an identical error message to before I had added anything.  The other similar .lib files that exist are `msvcmrt.lib`,`msvcmrtd`,`msvcprtd`,`msvcrtd`,`msvcurt`,and `msvcurtd`.  What are the differences between these library files, and how does someone choose which one to use?

Comment: Why do you link your application twice? Maybe you have forgot to link agains the CRT?

Comment: @JochenKalmbach I tried linking against the CRT, see new info in my question.  The .log file generated by the IDE lists that link command twice.  I never got to that because the linker error occurs the first time.

Comment: Why do you want to build it directly with "cl"? Why not use the devenv to build your project on the command line???? Also in the project settings, you will see the cl/link command lines in the advanced options.

Comment: @JochenKalmbach I need to run the project through a code analysis tool that needs to have working build and link commands to function.

I noticed the commands in the advanced options.  They were almost identical to the ones I had been using, and they yielded the same results.  I've also tried doing this in the VS Command prompt with the same results.

I'd really like to know what the IDE's doing that I'm not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I know how to fix it.

In your project, you choose a non GUI project : it is a mistake and to fix it choose (I dont known the exact names, I use VS in French)

```
option->Link options->System->Sub-système=Windows
```

and it should work